# ios Twitter API JSON parsing

Tags: ios, json, twitter

I'm trying to parse the JSON string received by the Twitter API to get the user timeline.
I'm using Jastor to convert the JSON response to objective c objects. 
Everything works fine until I try to parse the **entities** object

```
entities = {
        hashtags =();
        media = (
                 {
                "display_url" = "pic.twitter.com/...";
                "expanded_url" = "http://...";
                id = ...;
                "id_str" = ...;
                indices =(
                    5,
                    25
                );
                "media_url" = "http://...";
                "media_url_https" = "https://...";
                sizes ={
                    large ={
                        h = 765;
                        resize = fit;
                        w = 1024;
                    };
                    medium ={
                        h = 448;
                        resize = fit;
                        w = 600;
                    };
                    small ={
                        h = 254;
                        resize = fit;
                        w = 340;
                    };
                    thumb ={
                        h = 150;
                        resize = crop;
                        w = 150;
                    };
                };
                type = photo;
                url = "http://...";
            }
        );
        urls =();
        "user_mentions" = ();
    };
```

Even if the JSON is not standard Jastor seems to parse all of it but this block due to the presence of "(" ")".
Do you know how to allow Jastor to parse this block as well? Or do I have to change library?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the whole JSON chunk you're getting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's curious with the output of your question is that it is not a JSON formatted string. It looks like a nested combination of `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` objects which is typical when you convert a JSON string into Objective-C objects. When you `NSLog` this sort of object, the curly braces indicate `NSDictionary` objects and the parentheses indicate `NSArray` objects.

So, it just looks like you're displaying a typical, successfully parsed JSON object. You can decipher it as follows, assuming that the above output was generated by doing a `NSLog` of some `NSDictionary` called, say, `jsonObject`:

```
NSDictionary *entity  = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"entities"];
NSArray *media        = [entity objectForKey:@"media"];
NSDictionary *media0  = [media objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *display_url = [media0 objectForKey:@"display_url"];
NSArray *sizes        = [media0 objectForKey:@"sizes"];
NSDictionary *size0   = [sizes objectAtIndex:0];
```

or, if using modern Objective C, simply:

```
NSDictionary *entity  = jsonObject[@"entities"];
NSArray *media        = entity[@"media"];
NSDictionary *media0  = media[0];
NSString *display_url = media0[@"display_url"];
NSArray *sizes        = media0[@"sizes"];
NSDictionary *size0   = sizes[0];
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using the new feature in iOS 5.0 NSJSONSerialization, it converts JSON data to Objective C standarts like NSArray or NSDictionary.

```
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", kTwitterApi, kParams];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL]];
request.HTTPMethod = @"GET";

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }else {
        NSError *err;
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&err];

        NSLog(@"%@", json);
    }

}];
```

Comment: That's exactly what I do. I use NSJSONSerialization to convert JSON to NSArray (of NSDictionary).
The Obj C class (Tweet) I use to represent the tweet is subclass of Jastor, so once I have the NSDictionary all I have to do is 
Tweet *t = [[Tweet alloc] initWithDictionary:dic]; to get the object.

Comment: I got it.. Never used automatic model builders though. Always created model logic by myself to avoid bugs and mistakes, and to support all NSCoding features in my object.